# What is the difference between StatefullWidget and StatelessWidget regards to Performance?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a Performance impact if we just use StatefullWidget over the StatelessWidget it vice-versa?

In my point of view, we just use `StatefullWidget` for things like update part of the UI using `setState()`, have a way to setup some code in the `initState()` and dispose things in the `dispose()` function. So when I don't need those things I go ahead and use `StatelessWidget`.

But what is the real performance impact between these two most used widgets?

Comment: Please read this https://fluttercentral.com/Articles/Post/14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performance-wise, a `StatelessWidget` is almost identical to a `StatefulWidget` with an empty `State`.

Writing:

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

or:

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

won't have any visible impact on the performance of your app.

There indeed is a small gain when using `StatelessWidget` here. But it's ridiculously small:

The difference between them can be summarized as calling an empty function vs not calling it. It's something, but absolutely doesn't matter.

---

The reason being, internally the implementation of `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget` is almost the same.

`StatelessWidget` *does* have all the extra life-cycles that `StatefulWidget` possess. 
It has an "initState"/"dispose". Even a `setState`!
They are just not part of the public API.

Comment: why not make everything a stateful then?

Comment: @TiagoSantos Because if you build an app only with stateful widget, even when isn't needed, you can would create unnecessary boilerplate code. It isn't the best approach regarding readability.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a StatelessWidget?**

> A widget that does not require mutable state.

**Performance considerations**

> The build method of a stateless widget is typically only called in three situations: the first time the widget is inserted in the tree, when the widget's parent changes its configuration, and when an InheritedWidget it depends on changes.

**Sample Code**

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget ({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(color: const Color(0xFF00BD3A));
  }
}
```

**What is a StatefulWidget?**

> A widget that has mutable state.

**Performance considerations**

> here are two primary categories of StatefulWidgets.
>
> The first is one which allocates resources in State.initState and disposes of them in State.dispose, but which does not depend on InheritedWidgets or call State.setState. Such widgets are commonly used at the root of an application or page, and communicate with subwidgets via ChangeNotifiers, Streams, or other such objects. Stateful widgets following such a pattern are relatively cheap (in terms of CPU and GPU cycles), because they are built once then never update. They can, therefore, have somewhat complicated and deep build methods.
>
> The second category is widgets that use State.setState or depend on InheritedWidgets. These will typically rebuild many times during the application's lifetime, and it is therefore important to minimize the impact of rebuilding such a widget. (They may also use State.initState or State.didChangeDependencies and allocate resources, but the important part is that they rebuild.)

**Sample code**

```
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => new _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```

Full Explanaton is [given here](https://fluttercentral.com/Articles/Post/14)